# iOS app for listing items on Amazon?

Tags: ios, amazon

I have a small business selling old books on Amazon.com (self-fulfilled, I'm not using their fullfilment). I'd like to be able to list books from my iOS device.

Must:

- Have advanced search
- Allow me to list an item, specifying

  - Condition
  - Notes
  - Price
- Ability to scan barcodes

Nice to have:

- View seller feedback
- View recent orders
- Manage existing inventory

Is there an iOS app the meets this criteria?